# Android TextWatcher Replace Underscores While Typing

Tags: android, textwatcher

Intro: 
I am currently trying to implement an input method for an `EditText` for my Crossword Puzzle where the user sees something like `"____"` in the `EditText`. The underscores mark missing letters, the first char entered will fill the first underscore.
Of course other cells in the puzzle might be solved already, so the `EditText` text could be `"ST_CKOV_RF_OW"`. I had all this functionality already in my own input view, a subclass of view with an overridden `onDraw()`. This worked pretty well, except that the view won't appear on some lower Android versions and the Back key slipped through my input routine and wasn't accessible.

So I thought I'd do it with `EditText`, implement a `TextWatcher` and be fine, but I can't get it to work properly. What I have right now is working, I can use the keyboard to enter letters, but again the Backspace isn't working, and of course if the user touches into the `EditText` the position gets messed up.

```
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s,int start,int count, int after){
                    et.removeTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
                    int position = text.indexOf("_");
                    if(position==-1) onAnswerEntered(et.getText().toString().replace("_", "")); //finished
                    else {
                        et.setSelection(et.getText().toString().indexOf("_"));
                        et.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
                    }
                } 


public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    et.removeTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
                    try {                   
                        String currentKey = s.toString().substring(start, start+1);
                        Logger.log("Current Key", currentKey);

                        int position = text.indexOf("_");
                        Logger.log("Current Position _ ", position+"");

                        //replace _ with key
                        String sbefore=text.substring(0, position);
                        String safter=text.substring(position+1, text.length());
                        text=sbefore+currentKey+safter;

                        int positionNext = text.indexOf("_");
                        Logger.log("Next Position _ ", positionNext+"");

                        if(positionNext==-1) onAnswerEntered(et.getText().toString().replace("_","")); //finished
                        else {
                            et.setText(text);
                            et.setSelection(et.getText().toString().indexOf("_"));
                            et.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
                        }


                    } catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException ioobe) {
                        ioobe.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
```

I also tried to set an `OnKeyListener`, but it won't work on `EditText` (I can get backspace event, nothing else)

So maybe I am totally on the wrong track, but please help me and give me a clue to how I can  accomplish my goal. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I gave up on it and implemented a simple but working kind of hack. I receive input in my (hidden) EditText now, the output goes to the visible TextView, a function in between fills the "_" with the input from the EditText.
Ex.

hint = "A_A_A_A"
edittext input = "BBB"
textview shows "ABABABA"